# Spring form validate : Whitelabel Error Page

Tags: spring

```
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/add")
    public ModelAndView add() throws ConferenceNotFoundException {
        LOGGER.debug("Getting adding page");
        return new ModelAndView("conference/add", "form", new ConferenceForm());
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/add")
    public String handleAddConferenceForm(@Valid @ModelAttribute("form") ConferenceForm form,
                                          BindingResult bindingResult,
                                          @ModelAttribute("currentUser") CurrentUser currentUser) {
        LOGGER.debug("Processing add conference form={}, bindingResult={}", form, bindingResult);

        form.setHost(currentUser.getUser());

        if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
            // failed validation
            return "conference/add";
        }
        try {
            conferenceService.create(form);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // ok, redirect
        return "redirect:/";
    }
```

[image]

I make spring form like above the code. And it works well like above the picture.

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/{id}/admin/update")
public ModelAndView update(Model model,
                           @PathVariable("id") Long id) throws ConferenceNotFoundException {
    LOGGER.debug("Getting update page");

    Conference conference = conferenceService.findById(id);
    model.addAttribute("conference", conference);
    return new ModelAndView("conference/update", "form", new ConferenceForm(conference));
}

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/{id}/admin/update")
public String handleUpdateConferenceForm(@Valid @ModelAttribute("form") ConferenceForm form,
                                         @PathVariable("id") Long id,
                                         BindingResult bindingResult,
                                         @ModelAttribute("currentUser") CurrentUser currentUser) {
    LOGGER.debug("Processing update conference form={}, bindingResult={}", form, bindingResult);

    form.setHost(currentUser.getUser());

    if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
        // failed validation
        return "conference/update";
    }
    try {
        conferenceService.update(form, id);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // ok, redirect
    return "redirect:/conferences/" + id + "/admin";
}
```

[image]

Otherwise, above the code does not work well. It's validator works well and it update the contents. But it generate `Whitelabel Error Page` when validator works.

I don't know why it generate `Whitelabel Error Page`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found what the problem is.

Change `BindingResult bindingResult`'s location.

From:

```
public String handleUpdateConferenceForm(@Valid @ModelAttribute("form") ConferenceForm form,
                                     @PathVariable("id") Long id,
                                     BindingResult bindingResult,
                                       @ModelAttribute("currentUser") CurrentUser currentUser)
```

To:

```
public String handleUpdateConferenceForm(@Valid @ModelAttribute("form") ConferenceForm form,
                                             BindingResult bindingResult,
                                             Model model,
                                             @PathVariable("id") Long id,
                                             @ModelAttribute("currentUser") CurrentUser currentUser)
```

Comment: Even though I had different parameters, changing the order up solved the problem for me too. Weirdly enough, I would say.

Comment: I spent 2 hours till I got this solution. Weird behavior

Answer (score 0):

Thank you. I had similar issue. BindingResult must come before Model on the arguments. Otherwise, it will send you Whitelabel Error Page from Model.